# Getting a image from http server and display it ciclicaly in smart tv

Tags: javascript, jquery, jpeg, samsung-smart-tv

So I'm trying to make an app for Samsung smart TVs. I'm creating the smart TV app with App framework 2.0 which should have 4 image squares.

those 4 squares should be the JPEG images of CCTV cameras which I should get and display periodically on those image squares (between 1 and 5 seconds).

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

so for I created a image and tried this:

```
$('#image1').sfImage({
        url:'https://10.0.0.164/jpeg/image.jpeg'
    });
```

But this doesn't even get the image from the URL.
Should there be like a "show" command or something? Where can I get a list of methods/functions and examples that could help me get better at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used SF framework myself, but [sfImage documentation](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/API00002/sfImage_11.html) has following sample code:

```
$('#image').sfImage({src:'images/samsung.jpg'});
$('#image').sfImage('hide');
```